# Position dynamically generated cards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I am working on angular application. My code is as follows

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-example-57kjum?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

In this I have cards. One single mat-card. Other cards I am generating dynamically on the basis of data in array. Problem I am facing is dynamically generated cards using *ngFor are starting below first card. I want to have first card at first place then from near to it these dynamically generated cards should start  and if space is not left at first line then card should come to second line and on third and so on. It seems I am doing some mistake in diving page in col and row, but not sure though. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

put the contents of the card in a div and in the css put this
min width: max content; like that, the div will take the size of the carte content

Comment: Hi could you please update my stackblitz so that I can get better idea what you saying

Comment: hi again i tried it on your code but it give the result that you said that mean that you messing bootstrap file or something and here a link to  handful of options for alignment on bootstrap documentation by the way it york fine on my code https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/ i hope it was helpful